# Embedded htm file within html page not showing £ signs

Tags: html, iframe, embed

I have a webpage that has a xls file converted to a htm file, the issue is that the £ signs are showing as �.

This obviously is a charset issue, however when I open the htm file in a webbrowser the £ sign shows, the only time it shows the � is when its in an Iframe or embed tag.

I tried adding `content="text/html; charset=utf-8"` to the embed tag but that didn't change anything.

Is there a way to either show the htm file inside the div without using embed or iframe that shows the £ signs or a way to change the charset.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the source code of the converted file. How are the pound symbols being defined?

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. The file is not encoded as UTF-8 (which is a shame in the 21st century) *or*
2. You got the syntax for your meta tag wrong (`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in HTML 4, `<meta charset="utf-8">` in modern HTML) *or*
3. Something else (a real HTTP header) is overriding the charset specification

I'd bet on option 1 and wouldn't be surprised if Excel has exported the file as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: The generated htm file had the Windows-1252 charset.  I changed it to utf-8 and nothing changed though.